# Criando uma ferramenta CLI com NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cliente-servidor

Estou aprendendo a criar uma ferramenta CLI (Command-Line Interface Applications)

e realizei as seguintes etapas:

criei uma pasta e dentro dela no terminal rodei

```
npm init--yes
```

com isso eu gerei o `package.json` nessa pasta eu criei uma pasta bin e dentro dela um arquivo index.js

depois disso arrumei o package.json para que ele torne index.js como um executavel atraves do comando `forecast`

```
{
  "name": "tableless-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
    "forecast": "./bin/index.js"
  }
}
```

coloquei este codigo no index.js

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
  var https = require('https')
  var arguments = process.argv.splice(2, process.argv.length -1).join(' ')
  console.log(arguments);
```

no terminal eu rodei:

```
npm link
forecast
```

para transformar em executável e forecast foi o que defini em package.json

abri o cmd fui na pasta no lugar aonde tem o package.json e rodei forecast test e da erro. fala que forecast é um comando invalido, aonde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem **2 coisas** estranhas em seu código, que pode ser o problema.

Primeiro sua sintaxe **shebang** me parece errada (não tenho certeza):

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```

Provavelmente deveria ser sem espaço após o `#!` (shebang):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

A segunda é que parece que você esta usando Windows, eu não sei dizer se esse é o mesmo processo ou se é automatizado ou não, mas é quase certo que o "compilador" irá gerar um `.cmd` (ou `.bat`)

Note que para instalar creio que o comando esteja errado:

```
npm init--yes
```

Deveria ser:

```
npm init --yes
```

Ou talvez nem precise do `--yes`:

```
npm init
```